# Comparing columns of different size with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, A and B. I need to create a third column that when the numbers in A matches the numbers in B it writes correct otherwise it marks it a null. any suggestions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxhwk.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [100]: A
Out[100]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5

In [101]: B
Out[101]:
   a
2  3
3  4
4  5

In [102]: A['Result'] = A['a'].isin(B['a'] ).replace( {False : None , True : 'correct' })

In [103]: A
Out[103]:
   a   Result
0  1     None
1  2     None
2  3  correct
3  4  correct
4  5  correct
```